# Declare Scalar variable Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Customer
( FName varchar(20),LName varchar(20),Birthdate datetime,Email Nvarchar(20),Houseno varchar(20),Street varchar(20),City varchar(20),Country varchar(20),Pincode int,Phno varchar(13),Mobile varchar(13),CustomerId varchar(20),Password varchar(20),ConfirmPassword varchar(20))

AS

Begin

   Insert into Registration values 
  (@FName,@LName,@Birthdate,@Email,@Houseno,@Street,@City,@Country,
   @Pincode,@Phno, @Mobile,@CustomerId,@Password,@ConfirmPassword)

End
```

While saving error comes as

> Fname must be declare as Scalar variable

Whats wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `"@"` sign for your parameter declarations.

```
create procedure Customer
@FName varchar(20),@LName varchar(20) .....
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables you are trying to insert have not been declared correctly. You must prefix all of the declarations with @.

```
create procedure Customer
(@FName varchar(20),@LName varchar(20),@Birthdate datetime,@Email Nvarchar(20),@Houseno varchar(20),@Street varchar(20),@City varchar(20),@Country varchar(20),@Pincode int,@Phno varchar(13),@Mobile varchar(13),@CustomerId varchar(20),@Password varchar(20),@ConfirmPassword varchar(20))
AS
Begin
Insert into Registration values (@FName,@LName,@Birthdate,@Email,@Houseno,@Street,@City,@Country,@Pincode,@Phno,
@Mobile,@CustomerId,@Password,@ConfirmPassword)
End
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define your local variable as @local_variable, see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql)

> @local_variable
>   Is the name of a variable. Variable names must begin with an at (@) sign. Local variable names must comply with the rules for

With @, it tell sqlserver that it is local variable. Also you define @ while insert.

As above all suggested, just add @ before each parameter name.